# Calculate probability of meeting.

Tags: probability

My friend and I decided to meet between 1 and 3 PM today.
There is a condition that whoever arrives first will not wait for the other for more than 20 minutes.
what is the probability that we'll meet today?

Comment: Probably not your fault because questions like this are often given as homework, but it really is an annoying question. Are you supposed to assume that the arrival times of you and your friend are uniformly distributed between 1 and 3 PM?

Comment: yes,arrival times are uniformly distributed.

Comment: To help you get started, read [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1100090/an-example-of-a-problem-which-is-difficult-but-is-made-easier-when-a-diagram-is/1100120#1100120), which deals with a slightly different problem. You just have to think of the two arrival times as points on an interval.

Comment: Look at the Related column on the right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image] $$20 min=\frac{1}{3}$$ hour
meeting condition equal to $|x-y|<\frac{1}{3} $
$$S=\{(x,y)|  0\leq x\leq 2 ,0\leq y\leq 2\}$$ that means 1 to 3 pm ,for each person 2 hour is possible 
  $$ p(|x-y|<\frac{1}{3})=\frac{shaded \space area }{2*2}$$

Comment: To produce curly braces, type \{ and \} in math mode.