# Geometry/Trigonometry Determine angle in a Triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

Triangle ABC is isosceles with BC as base, AB=AC and Angle A=20 degrees. Points D and E lie on sides AB and AC respectively, such that D lies between A and B, E lies between A and C, angle BCD=50 degrees, angle CBE=60 degrees. Determine Angle ADE.

Edit: I have tried to solve this question with simple additions/subtractions of angles with and without additional geometric constructions to achieve the goal but in vain. Is there a solution that does not involve trigonometry?

Comment: Have you tried drawing a picture?

Comment: Yes, and I assure you it's not trivial.

Comment: this is a very well known problem. see http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/BotCan/Solution/Solution.html

Comment: Duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/6942/409

Comment: Thank you, I supposed this was just an adhoc geometry problem as the friend who have this to me did not mention anything about it having such a history. What should I do to remove it?