# Solve for $x$ in the $80^\circ$-$80^\circ$-$20^\circ$ triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]
I've been solving this for days but I still I couldn't solve this. Can I know how to solve $x$ ?

Comment: Similar (although one angle is different): ["Finding an angle within an 80-80-20 isosceles triangle"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/finding-an-angle-within-an-80-80-20-isosceles-triangle)

Comment: It would help to label the vertices so as to facilitate naming angles.

Comment: You can find the desired angle by using the notions of complementary and supplementary angles and the fact that the three interior angles of a triangle sum to $180^{\circ}$.

Comment: As a note: The picture is not accurate to the actual _proportions_ of the triangles with the given angles (in the case that you find your answer does not appear to agree with the picture, this is probably why).

Comment: Remember that all angles within a triangle add up to 180 degrees.  Break this whole thing up into many triangles and work out the angles around them using what you have starting with the very top point

Comment: This Question (a version of Langley's problem) is the designated duplicate target for another Question, so I'm voting to leave open.  See the list of linked Questions at right on the desktop site.

Answer (score 2):

I fail to see the importance and difficulty of Langley’s Problem mentioned by Justin Benfield in his answer here apart perhaps some historical mention or maybe some interesting applications. In effect, here I give an EASY generalization of the problem proposed by the OP. I would appreciate any substantiated comment against (am I wrong?).

Let $\triangle{ABC}$ not necessarily isosceles. Given side $a$ and angles $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta$ determine the angles $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3,x,y$ as well as the segments $BE,BD,CD$ and the  said difficulty would be to determine $x$ or $y$ since $\phi_1,\phi_2,\phi_3$  are  immediate to calculate

[image]

We have
$$BE=\frac{\sin \beta}{\sin \phi_1}\cdot a\\BD=\frac{\sin \phi_3}{\sin \phi_2}\cdot a\\CD=\frac{\sin \alpha}{\sin \phi_2}\cdot a\\ED=BE\cdot\frac{\sin \delta}{\sin x}=\frac{\sin \beta\sin\delta}{\sin \phi_1\sin x}\cdot a $$ It follows the easy system
$$\begin{cases}x+y=\phi_3\\\space\\\dfrac{\sin (\phi_1+\phi_3-x)}{\sin x}=\dfrac{\sin\phi_1\sin\phi_3}{\sin\beta\sin\phi_2}\end{cases}$$ This gives an elementary equation of the form $$A\sin x+B\cos x=C$$ one of the quite popular way to solve is the following:
$$A\sin x+B\cos x=C\iff\frac{A\sin x}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}+\frac{B\cos x}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}=\frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$ so $$x+\theta= \arcsin{\frac{C}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}}\space\text{where } \space \theta=\arccos{\frac{A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Your's is a version of Langley's problem, with slightly different angles. It shouldn't be too difficult to adapt the solution presented here: http://www.gogeometry.com/LangleyProblem.html to your current problem.

Note that this is problem's solution is rather clever, and involves constructing a new edge rather than simple angle chasing (I spent quite a lot of time trying to solve it with angle chasing arguments to no avail before resorting to google searching about it, only to find out that angle chasing didn't cut it, and hence I am now writing this answer).

Comment: A solution for your variant (that is flipped horizontally from how you have it), can be found here: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/60-70Sol1.shtml#solution

Comment: Sorry I don't understand the solution well... In this website, why ∠BDF = 30°?

Comment: It can be shown fairly easily by angle-chasing using the fact that $\angle$BCF was constructed to be $50^{\circ}$.

Comment: could you show the details please?

Comment: @RayCheng After futzing with the problem for a bit, I realized it's not a matter of simple angle chasing, when the author of what I linked referred to the 'classical framework' he was referring to how the newly constructed edge, and the $60^{\circ}$ angle opposite it, are like the classic version of the problem to which that text links, there you will find 12 different approaches to solving that problem, from that solution, the one to the present problem can be derived in the manner the author describes.

Comment: Can you provide the link which states 12 different approaches to solve the problem?

Comment: Click on the words Classical Framework, you will taken here: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/IndexToClassical.shtml

Comment: Could you show the detail steps of the 10-70-20-60 triangle please? The website only talks about how to do 30-50-20-60 triangle and I don't know how to apply the method into the 10-70-20-60 triangle.