# How to solve this $80^\circ$-$80^\circ$-$20^\circ$ triangle ($60^\circ+20^\circ$ and $70^\circ+10^\circ$ variant)?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

A friend of mine asked me for help with a math problem and I struggled with this for over an hour. I told him sorry, and I felt bad. It's been bugging me now for hours. I don't even so much care for the answer of A, I just want to know how it should be done.

[image]

Comment: Please stare what were thegiven details and you have found out in the image

Comment: This figure cannot exist. Note that the triangle at the top totals 310 degrees, however the sum of the triangle's interior angles should only add up to 180 degrees (as a property of all triangles). **In short: you've been given an invalid problem.** :)

Comment: @SirJony No it does not! 140 and 150 are the angles of the quadrilateral, not the top triangle

Comment: @Qwerty and Frank --  Oh, pardon me. I misread the left angle. Well, this makes the problem a lot easier. :)

Comment: This is a "world-wide" known problem called "World's hardest easy geometry problem" and has already been answered. $\angle{A}=20$ (Link: https://www.duckware.com/tech/worldshardesteasygeometryproblem.html)

Comment: Its "world-wide"-ness didn't reach the west coast of the US yet. :) It shouldn't be to hard to solve for those who haven't heard of it (such as me), though.

Comment: Which is why I put quotation marks around world wide... :)

Comment: @Blue and schardulc -- 2 duplicates? Someone wasn't their job earlier. :)

Comment: @SirJony: Well, only the one I listed is an *exact* duplicate. (That's why, when I edited the title, I specified the "variant".)

Comment: @Blue -- Yes, I understand. I was just saying that that you and shardulc each showed a duplicate, and wouldn't one of them been a duplicate of the other way back when the newer of the two was asked? :)

Comment: @SirJony: Actually, the very first comment under [the post I reference](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738400/solve-for-x-in-the-80-circ-80-circ-20-circ-triangle) is from me, noting that the question is related to the other one, but with different angles. I wasn't inclined to close a variant as a duplicate. (Apparently, neither was anyone else, as the question got no close votes.) So, I did my job! ;)

Comment: @Blue -- Alright, I get it. A job well done, I suppose. :)