# Find angle x in the triangle.

Tags: geometry

I am puzzled by this question.

I tried all triangle angle formulas, and every time I end up reaching `x + y = 130`.

[image]

I am sure I am missing one essential property. If anybody please solve this and possibly remind me of which property I forgot to use.

Comment: It was in my notebook. :| Updated the picture.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/finding-an-angle-within-an-80-80-20-isosceles-triangle

Comment: This is sometimes called Langley's problem.  The question is answered at least once on this site here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/finding-an-angle-within-an-80-80-20-isosceles-triangle

Comment: This is a very famous problem and you can check the answer at this site: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/60-70Sol1.shtml

Answer (score 0):

Here is the general solution to this problem.
[image]