# Is this geometry problem uniquely solvable?

Tags: geometry

Knowing AC = BC, find x.

[image]

I tried to solve the question and found many angles.

[image]

And x + k = 110, x + y = 140, k + z = 130, z + y = 160.

But I still can't find x. Is this problem uniquely solvable?

The book answer is x = 30°.

Comment: See https://www.duckware.com/tech/worldshardesteasygeometryproblem.html

Comment: You do have almost finish because calling $O$ the point $DB\cap AE$ you have dans le quadrilatere $OECD$ the sum
$$130^{\circ}+90^{\circ}+110^{\circ}+x=360^{\circ}$$
Hence $x=30^{\circ}$

Comment: See Wikipedia entry on [Langley's Adventitious Angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%E2%80%99s_Adventitious_Angles).

Comment: Piquito, why is y = 110º ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this problem is solvable and there are distinct solutions.[image]

And this is pure geometric solution:
[image]

And more easier solution is:
[image]

And my final solution:
[image]

Comment: You mean distinct way to solve because the solution is unique

Comment: @Seyed: Since the question has been closed as a duplicate, you might want to move your answer to [this previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/finding-an-angle-within-an-80-80-20-isosceles-triangle), where it may get more attention over time. Also, you shouldn't use images as main content of your post. Doing so makes your text impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired. Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/)).

Comment: @Blue, Thanks for your useful advices. I sent my answers to that question. In the future I will try to separate images from the main content. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice compilation of solutions. I like the third one! (+1)