# An angle in an $80^\circ$-$80^\circ$-$20^\circ$ triangle?

Tags: geometry

In this picture $AB=AC$ and

$\begin{array}{l}
 \angle A = 20 \\ 
 \angle {B_1} = 70 \\ 
 \angle {C_1} = 60 \\ 
 \end{array}$

What is $\angle x$?

[image]

Comment: The angle of the vertex $x$?

Comment: @Filburt - Please more guide.

Comment: Related: ["Finding an angle within an 80-80-20 isosceles triangle"](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/finding-an-angle-within-an-80-80-20-isosceles-triangle), where the known angles are a little different. (In that form, this is [Langley's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley’s_Adventitious_Angles). See also [Cut-the-Knot's entry](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/Classical4.shtml#Knop) on the problem.)