# What is wrong in my solution attempt to the $80^\circ$-$80^\circ$-$20^\circ$ problem?

Tags: geometry, angle

I'm trying to solve the following famous problem:
[image]

Here's my attempt, for some reason it leads to a contradiction, where have I gone wrong?

[image]

Please do not give me any hints on how to solve the problem on a whole, as I want to solve it on my own. If I'm wrong I'll try another approach, but I'd like to know where I have went wrong.

Comment: can you add some text to the picture?

Comment: Which one are you talking about?

Comment: 70 is easily 180 - 50 - 60, and by that you can get the 4 angles in the middle (70, 110, 70, 110) ----- then you can use that the angles of the triangle sum to 180 to get the remaining

Comment: Looks like you made a simple mistake when hunting for the angles in your first diagram implication.

Comment: When you are interested in a full solution, visit [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/finding-an-angle-within-an-80-80-20-isosceles-triangle).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angles B and C equal 80 degrees each. with angle A equaling 40 degrees, the sum of degrees is 200, not 180.

Answer (score 3):

The angle at the top of the triangle is not $40^\circ$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 180 - (The 2 bottom angles) = 40?

Comment: The two bottom angles sum to $80+80=160$, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: ugh such an amateur mistake rip my bad