# Angle in a 80-80-20 triangle

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

Let $ABC$ be isosceles triangle $(AB=AC)$ with $\angle BAC = 20^{\circ}$. Point $D$ is on side $AC$ such that $\angle DBC = 60^{\circ}$. Point $E$ is on side $AB$ such that $\angle ECB = 50^{\circ}$. Find $\angle EDB $

---

Solution:

Let $x=\angle EDB $. We see that $BC = BE$

By sinus theorem for $BCE$ and $BCD$ we have $${\sin x\over \sin (x+20^{\circ})}={BE\over BD} = {\sin 40^{\circ}\over \sin 80^{\circ}} = {1\over 2\cos 40^{\circ}} $$
From here we get $$\tan x = {\sin 20^{\circ}\over 2\cos 40^{\circ}-\cos 20^{\circ}}$$
and it is not difficult to see (after some algebraic manipulation) that $x = 30^{\circ}$

---

**Here is a question**: Is there a neat synthetic soultion to this problem?

Comment: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/triangle/80-80-20/IndexToClassical.shtml

Comment: OMG, thanks!!!!

Comment: Hmm, should I delete this one now?

Comment: @ChristianF, no, Aretino should turn that comment into an answer :)

Comment: @ChristianF: Actually, deletion would be appreciated. There are a zillion $80^\circ$-$80^\circ$-$20^\circ$ duplicates floating around here.

Comment: Searching 20 80 80 on this site will give some other questions and answers on the same topic, but your question is well written, I think it may be useful to other people and suggest to leave it in place.

Comment: Once upon a time, this problem let me win a competition :D Here it is another reference: http://static.elitesecurity.org/uploads/1/9/1987242/Geometry%20Problem.pdf

Comment: The (good!) solution given in this question statement should probably be submitted as an answer to a previous version of the question.

Comment: My personal favorite is #5 at Cut the Knot, which is also solution number 2 here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2007349

Comment: Can you give a clue on how to solve the trigonometric equation? What algebraic manipulation did you use?