# In an isosceles triangle with base $AB$ and $\angle CAB=80^\circ$ taken $D$ on $CA$, $E$ on $CB$ such that ...

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry

For the well-known problem

> In an isosceles triangle with base $AB$ and $\angle CAB=80^\circ$ taken $D$ on the segment $CA$, $E$ on the segment $CB$ such that $\angle BAE=60^\circ$, $\angle ABD=50^\circ$, find $\angle EDB$.

The question is what is a canonical or otherwise simple without being too artificial way of solving it? Or what was the solution you heard/seen/found first?
[image]
Btw, simple angle chasing does not help. The first way I can think of is considering difference of heights $DH_d$ and $EH_e$ of triangles $ABD$ and $ABE$ respectively along with $H_dH_e$ which together give the inclination angle of $DE$ relative to $AB$ and thus the desired angle. Needed for that lengths of $AD,\,BD,\,AE,\,BE$ can be expressed in terms of $AB$ and known angles by the sine rule. Almost like putting the thing into Cartesian coordinates.

Another approach could be vectors, then taking $A$ or $B$ as the origin makes things more simple, than taking $CA,\,CB$ as basis vectors, IMHO.

By "too artificial" I mean things like this:
[image]
constructing a regular $18$-gon with side $AB$, proving lines $AE,\,BD,\,DE$ contain some diagonals and then finding the angle very easy by angle chasing.

**Update**:

> The solutions are not as trivial as one would expect from the statement. It's called [Langley's problem of adventitious angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langley%E2%80%99s_Adventitious_Angles) first posed in The Mathematical Gazette in 1922.
> Check out [An Intriguing Geometry Problem by Tom Rike](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20160325182408/http://mathcircle.berkeley.edu/BMC4/Handouts/geoprob.pdf).

(from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/6945)).

Comment: So what is the answer? 80 degrees, right?

Comment: @peter.petrov By the last picture it's easy to see that the angle is half-sum of two subtended arcs of the circumcircle of the $18$-gon, each of them of $4$ chords of $20^\circ$, hence $80^\circ$. Geogebra gives $80^\circ$ too. And the results of algebraical computations simplify to $80^\circ$ too, so I believe yes)

Comment: Draw a line through B parallel to AC. Extend AE and DE until they intersect with the line. Now some very nice things happen.

Comment: Yeah this leads to a solution. I can write it in detail tomorrow. One gets an isolescent trapezoid and a bunch of similar triangles and several tetragons inscribed in circles

Comment: No, I got deluded last night. Never mind... I will think some more, it's a nice problem :)

Comment: Ahh my question appears to be a [duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6942/finding-an-angle-within-an-80-80-20-isosceles-triangle)...

Answer (score 2):

The following solution can be found in Coxeter-Greitzer's book $\textit{Geometry Revisited}$ [Problem $4$ in the last set of exercises in Chapter $1$], one of my favourite books, also I will type out the solution just because it is so beautiful.

> Let $EF$, parallel to $AB$, meet $AC$ at $F$. Let $BF$ meet $AE$ at $G$.

> $\Delta ABG$ is equilateral $\implies AG = AB$.

> $\Delta BAD$ is isosceles $\implies AD = AB$. Hence $\Delta AGD$ is isosceles,
> $\angle AGD = 80^{\circ}, \ \angle FGD = 40^{\circ}$.
> Since $\angle DFG = 40^{\circ}$, $\Delta FDG$ is isosceles and $FD=DG$.

> Also,
> $EF = EG \implies \Delta GED \stackrel{\sim}{=} \Delta FED$, $DE$ bisects $\angle FEG$, and $\angle DEA = 30^{\circ} \implies \angle EDB =80^{\circ}$.

A solution I did on my own did not require any constructions, observed a pair or two of similar triangles and used only the sine rule a couple of times along with one useful formula
$$\sin(\theta)\sin\left(\theta-\dfrac{\pi}3\right)\sin\left(\theta+\dfrac{\pi}3\right)=\dfrac{\sin{(3\theta)}}4$$

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a very simple solution:
[image]

Comment: Although proving $D',C,E$ are collinear is like proving $\angle AED=\angle BEC$ which becomes the main part of the problem, and construction, used for this, much reminds the one, mentioned in OP for being too artificial, nevermind, (+1). What is the source of the solution, btw?

Comment: Found [the source](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2007349)

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin, You found the source, that was me.

Answer (score 1):

[image]
For an arbitrary isosceles triangle with given angles $\alpha,\> \beta$ and $\gamma$ shown in the graph, the trigonometric solution for the unknown angle $x$ is

$$ \cot x = \frac{ \cos\alpha \cos(\gamma+\alpha)}
{\sin\gamma\cos(\beta+\alpha)\cos(\beta-\alpha)}-\tan(\beta-\alpha)
$$

(which is derived from the sine rule applied to three triangles.) Then, substitute $\alpha=10$, $\beta= 60$ and $\gamma=50$ into the expression to get

\begin{align}
\cot x & = \frac1{\cos 70} -\tan 50 =\frac1{\sin20}-\frac{\cos40}{\sin40}\\
&= \frac{2\cos20-\cos40 }{ \sin40}= \frac{\cos20+\cos80}{ \sin40}\\
&= \frac{2\cos30\cos50}{\sin40}=\sqrt3
\end{align}

Thus, $x=30$ and in turn $\angle EDB = 80$.